# The Power of Love

Tags: riddle

> 1. My first is a line of people
> 2. My second is well known among circles
> 3. My third is the 4th

Who am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be

> Cupid?

My first is a line of people

> A queue, pronounced like "Cu" in "cupid".

My second is well known among circles

> "Pi"

My third is the 4th

> "D", the 4th letter of the alphabet.

Title:

> Cupid makes people fall in love.

Comment: Right. So much better than my answer, I feel dumb now. :P

Comment: Nice ! @Zimonze was close :p I'll try to make it harder next time

Comment: DId some more research, and turns out "queuepire" was shown as a misreading of "cupid"...

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> [A queuepire](https://www.google.ca/search?safe=strict&ei=WoxCW4eUK8fs5gK8m63IBw&q=queuepire&oq=queuepire&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1j0.127165.127165.0.127460.1.1.0.0.0.0.168.168.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.167....0.4vmZH_Hu0oo/) (Couldn't find better page)

My first is a line of people

> [A queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_area)

My second is well known among circles

> [Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi)

My third is the 4th

> [Re](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_(musical_note)) (Equivalent to D, the 4th letter in the alphabet)